# Why matplotlib replace a right parenthesis with "!" in latex expression?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm in the situation where I have to translate python expression to Latex Bitmap for the enduser (who feels confident enough to write python functions by himself but prefers to watch result in Latex).

I'm using Matplotlib.mathtext to do the job (from a translated latex raw string) with the following code.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm 
from matplotlib import mathtext

class LatexBitmapFactory():
    """ Latex Expression to Bitmap """
    mpl.rc('image', origin='upper')
    parser = mathtext.MathTextParser("Bitmap")

    mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
    DefaultProps = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(family = "sans-serif",\
                                                    style = "normal",\
                                                    weight = "medium",\
                                                    size = 6)
    # size is changed from 6 to 7 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def SetBitmap(self, _parent, _line, dpi = 150, prop = DefaultProps):
        bmp = self.mathtext_to_wxbitmap(_line, dpi, prop = prop)
        w,h = bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight()
        return wx.StaticBitmap(_parent, -1, bmp, (80, 50), (w, h))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mathtext_to_wxbitmap(self, _s, dpi = 150, prop = DefaultProps):
        ftimage, depth = self.parser.parse(_s, dpi, prop)
        w,h = ftimage.get_width(), ftimage.get_height()
        return wx.BitmapFromBufferRGBA(w, h, ftimage.as_rgba_str())


EXP = r'$\left(\frac{A \cdot \left(vds \cdot rs + \operatorname{Vdp}\left(ri, Rn, Hr, Hd\right) \cdot rh\right) \cdot \left(rSurf + \left(1.0 - rSurf\right) \cdot ft\right) \cdot \left(1.0 - e^{- \left(\left(lr + \frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(2\right)}{tem \cdot 86400.0}\right)\right) \cdot tFr \cdot 3600.0}\right)}{rc \cdot \left(lr + \frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(2\right)}{tem \cdot 86400.0}\right) \cdot tFr \cdot 3600.0} + 1\right)$'

class aFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title="Edition"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title=title, size=(600,400),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=25, vgap=4, hgap=4)
        panel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self)
        image_latex = LatexBitmapFactory().SetBitmap(panel, EXP)

        sizer.Add(image_latex, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        panel.SetupScrolling()


app = wx.App(redirect=True, filename="latexlog.txt")
frame = aFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

with size=6, the following picture is displayed
[image: Did you find the "!" ?]

with size=7, I have this one
[image: perfect !]

The latex expression is correct, the second picture is correct. I don't have any error message, just a right parenthesis replaced with "!".

If I continue writing the expression I still have "!" with size 6.

[image: T_T]

If the expression is simpler, the right parenthesis is correctly displayed.

Any idea to solve it ?

Comment: Someone can tell me if he can reproduce it ? All code required is written. (I'm using matplotlib 1.4.3).

Comment: I can reproduce at size 6 @user2652620.  I'll have a look at whether I can understand what's going on.

Comment: It's a very interesting - if you replace `\left(` ... `\right)` with `\left[` ... `\right]` - it all works as expected.  I rather suspect you might have found a bug.  I tried your expression in raw `latex` and it works fine (I'm guessing you've already tried that) - I thought maybe matplotlib didn't like `\operatorname` because it needs a `usepackage`, but changing to `mathrm` or removing didn't help.  Continuing to chase...

Comment: I can also reproduce the bug. I tried this expression: `EXP = r'$\left(\frac{\frac{\frac{M}{I}}{N}}{\frac{\frac{B}{U}}{G}}\right)$'` which works fine only for `size = 4`. No explanation for the moment either... I'll try to find something from the parentheses scaling.

Comment: Can someone please make sure this gets reported as a bug upstream?

Comment: Done - [number 5210](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5210)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR There is a bug in the following line of `mathtext.py` [Line 727](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mathtext.py#L727).  It relates the right parenthesis at size `Bigg` to an index `'\x21'`, but this is the index for an exclamation point.  The line with a bit of context reads

```
_size_alternatives = {
    '('          : [('rm', '('), ('ex', '\xa1'), ('ex', '\xb3'),
                    ('ex', '\xb5'), ('ex', '\xc3')],
    ')'          : [('rm', ')'), ('ex', '\xa2'), ('ex', '\xb4'),
                    ('ex', '\xb6'), ('ex', '\x21')],
```

I am not exactly sure which index to change to, but I suggest you change your local copy of `mathtext.py` to read as follows:

```
_size_alternatives = {
    '('          : [('rm', '('), ('ex', '\xa1'), ('ex', '\xb3'),
                    ('ex', '\xb5'), ('ex', '\x28')],
    ')'          : [('rm', ')'), ('ex', '\xa2'), ('ex', '\xb4'),
                    ('ex', '\xb6'), ('ex', '\x29')]
```

The parantheses this produces are a little over rounded as they are the basic parantheses, but they work.  Equally - you could substitute in the `bigg` size ones - `'\xb5'` and `'xb6'`

Reported on matplotlib github [Issue 5210](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5210)

---

I can reproduce this problem with `size=6` using the code as provided
(made the constant a bit bigger in case it was a width issue).  I cannot
reproduce the "fix" by setting `size = 7`, but I can if I go up to `size = 8` or higher - suggesting this might be a nasty edge case bug and possibly system dependent...

I did quite a bit of investigation / diagnosis (see below), but it seems there is a bug - reported on [matplotlib github here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5210).

However, reducing to a `matplotlib` only example yields a very nice
rendering as follows.  Note I've setup my matplotlib to use latex
rendering by default - but you can set the options explicitly for the
same results.

#### Code

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib as mpl

 mpl.rc('image', origin='upper')

 mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
 DefaultProps = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(family = "sans-serif",\
                                                 style = "normal",\
                                                 weight = "medium",\
                                                 size = 6)

 EXP = r'$\left(\frac{A \cdot \left(vds \cdot rs + \operatorname{Vdp}\left(ri, Rn, Hr, Hd\right) \cdot rh\right) \cdot \left(rSurf + \left(1.0 - rSurf\right) \cdot ft\right) \cdot \left(1.0 - e^{- \left(\left(lr + \frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(2\right)}{tem \cdot 86400.0}\right)\right) \cdot tFr \cdot 3600.0}\right)}{rc \cdot \left(lr + \frac{\operatorname{Log}\left(2\right)}{tem \cdot 86400.0}\right) \cdot tFr \cdot 3600.0} + 10589 \right)$'

 plt.title(EXP, fontsize=6)
 plt.gca().set_axis_off() # Get rid of the plotting axis for clarity

 plt.show()
```

#### Output

Output window cropped and zoomed a bit for clarity, but you can see the
bracket is rendered OK

[image: Formula rendered]

This suggests that the problem is either the way the matplotlib
rendering engine is being used, the output to bitmap, or the interaction
with `wxPython`

From experimentation, I noticed that if you increase the dpi to 300 the code works fine at `size = 6`, but starts to fail again at `size = 3`.  This implies the problem is that one of the libraries does not think it can render the element in a certain number of pixels.

#### Root cause

Diagnosing which bit was doing this is ***hard*** (IMO)

First, I added

```
    self.parser.to_png('D:\\math_out.png', _s, color=u'black', dpi=150)
```

as the first line of `mathtext_to_wxbitmap(self, _s, dpi = 150, prop = DefaultProps)`.  This gave a nice output `png`, making me think it probably wasn't the matplotlib parser at fault...  ***EDIT*** based on [@Baptiste's useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33002413/838992), I tested this a bit more.  Actually - if I explicitly pass in `fontsize` to this call, I can replicate the appearance of the exclamation point. Also, `dpi` passed into this call is ignored - so in my tests I am actually dealing with a 300 dpi image. So, focus should rest on the `MathTextParser` and it could be a dpi issue.

---

#### Further investigation

A bit more investigation - I monkey patched my matplotlib installation - putting in a `print(result)` directly after the call to `parseString()` [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mathtext.py#L2371).  With a working expression that goes fine and prints out a textual representation.  With the bugged scenario, I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\baptiste_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    parser.to_png(filename, s, fontsize=size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3101, in to_
png
    rgba, depth = self.to_rgba(texstr, color=color, dpi=dpi, fontsize=fontsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3066, in to_
rgba
    x, depth = self.to_mask(texstr, dpi=dpi, fontsize=fontsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3039, in to_
mask
    ftimage, depth = self.parse(texstr, dpi=dpi, prop=prop)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3012, in par
se
    box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2339, in par
se
    print(result[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1403, in __r
epr__
    ' '.join([repr(x) for x in self.children]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1403, in __r
epr__
    ' '.join([repr(x) for x in self.children]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1403, in __r
epr__
    ' '.join([repr(x) for x in self.children]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1403, in __r
epr__
    ' '.join([repr(x) for x in self.children]))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb3' in position 1:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

This indicates that the bug might originate in a mis-translated character - maybe a missing codepoint in the font?

I also noted that you can reproduce without the `N` letter in Baptiste's minimal example.

---

#### Further further investigation

Sticking some debug prints in _get_glyph within the BakomaFonts class. In the failing case, the code seems to be looking up an exclamation (u'!') when you'd expect it to be looking for u'\xc4' and returning parenrightBigg (i.e. where the corresponding left bracket is looking up u'\xc3' and returning parenleftBigg). In situations where it only uses parenrightbigg, there is no problem (this occurs for fontsize=5 in the given example but no others). The debug line I put in _get_glyph was:

```
print('Getting glyph for symbol',repr(unicode(sym)))
print('Returning',cached_font, num, symbol_name, fontsize, slanted)
```

I guess whether it needs the bigg or Bigg version is based on a combination of fontsize and dpi

OK - I think problem is in this line : https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mathtext.py#L727

this reads (with a little context):

```
_size_alternatives = {
    '('          : [('rm', '('), ('ex', '\xa1'), ('ex', '\xb3'),
                    ('ex', '\xb5'), ('ex', '\xc3')],
    ')'          : [('rm', ')'), ('ex', '\xa2'), ('ex', '\xb4'),
                    ('ex', '\xb6'), ('ex', '\x21')],   ## <---- Incorrect line.
```

the `'\x21'` is wrong - but I can't work out what the right one is `'\x29'` is close, but "too curved".  I guessed at `'\xc4'` following the pattern, but that is a down arrow.  Hopefully one of the core devs can easily lookup this number (decimal 195) against the glyph it renders and correct.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with this answer. My investigation also lead to the file [ft2font.cpp](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.4.3/src/ft2font.cpp#L154) of the Matplotlib project. Then, I use `to_png` from the `MathTextParser` object (to get rid of `wx`) with the expression I've already mentioned in a comment of the question. Even if I change the dpi, I still get the ugly exclamation point.

Comment: @Baptiste OK - well that's interesting, but I don't get the exclamation point with increased dpi (at 300dpi with `size=6`, at least).  I'm not entirely satisfied either. One option certainly is to output the `png` if that's what the OP wants - but I assume they want it as a `wx` widget.  What system are you testing on - maybe we can narrow it down. I've tested with Py2.7, mpl 1.4.3 on Windows 8.  I've been working on this for a few minutes here and ther over the hours since I first commented, but probably won't be able to do more today.

Comment: I've tested with Py 2.7.6, mpl 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I narrowed it down (c.f. my answer). Maybe we can try to fix it. It is surprising that no one has  previously found this bug. Sounds like nobody uses `matplotlib.mathtext` intensely...

Comment: @baptiste nice work! I'll try your version tomorrow. Maybe we can fix as you say...

Comment: OK - I've done some more testing. This seems to be a corner case bug in matplotlib. All the things in both my answer and yours replicate on my box. However, if I explicitly specify fontsize to the call to to_png() with my example, the exclamation point appears.

Comment: @Richard Great! We have a target now: `MathTextParser`.

Comment: Also, please check with current master/1.5.0rc2, there has been a bunch of work done to both how we bind the c++ layer in and a smaller amount of work to the parser and renderer.

Comment: @tcaswell No problem.  I noticed a few commits around this area as I was going through code for this...

Comment: Unfortunately, a fresh install straight from master on git still exhibits this problem

Comment: for Bakoma font, the method  "get_sized_alternatives_for_symbol" is overrided. the symbol '[' do not have multiple size and just have few translations  (# The fourth size of '[' is mysteriously missing from the BaKoMa font, so I've ommitted it for both '[' and ']'
So, i decided to do the same with ')'. something is missing. The alternative size for ')' become [('rm', ')'), ('ex', '\xa2'), ('ex', '\xb4')]. It solve the translation for tests i'v done. Does it help to find why Bakoma do not have the size for right parenthesis ? is it a bad index ?

Comment: @user2652620 Got it - see latest edit.  I wish I could find the right index to correct it.  I've added all the info to the github bug (it's definitely a bug).  If you want to "patch" it for now - change the `'\x21'` to `'\x29'` in your local `mathtext.py` - but the bracket that gives is wrong really - too curvy.  You could make the Bigg sized left parenthesis match by changing `'\xc3'` in the line above to `'\x28'`

Comment: Ok. For a deep understanding of the origin of bug continue on Github link as reported by @Richard. As far as tested, to solve the pb while waiting new matplotlib update, use in mathtext.py {
    '('          : [('rm', '('), ('ex', '\xa1'), ('ex', '\xb3'),
                    ('ex', '\xb5'), ('ex', '\x28')],
    ')'          : [('rm', ')'), ('ex', '\xa2'), ('ex', '\xb4'),
                    ('ex', '\xb6'), ('ex', '\x29')]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the shortest piece of code I was able to write to get this unexpected behavior:

```
import matplotlib.mathtext as mt

s = r'$\left(\frac{\frac{\frac{M}{I}}{N}}' \
    r'{\frac{\frac{B}{U}}{G}}\right)$'
parser = mt.MathTextParser("Bitmap")
for size in range(1, 30):
    filename = "figure{0}.png".format(size)
    parser.to_png(filename, s, fontsize=size)
```

The outputs look like this (a selection 6-12):

[image: size 6]

[image: size 7]

[image: size 8]

[image: size 9]

[image: size 10]

[image: size 11]

[image: size 12]

*This post was more to share the minimal code to reproduce the error rather than an answer to the question*

Comment: I get this on mostly current master/1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I still have "!" with dpi='300' at size 9, but around 9 and except 3, it's ok.

I made a new Frame to play with both dpi and size and with '()' and '[]'. Just reuse 'LatexBitmapFactory' to play.

I'm on windows XP, using python 2.7. I have the same error on Windows 7.

```
class aFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title="Edition"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title=title, size=(1300,600),
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self)


        init_dpi = 300
        min_dpi, max_dpi = 100, 500
        self.dpi_slider = wx.Slider(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                    init_dpi, min_dpi, max_dpi, (30, 60), (250, -1), 
                                    wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        init_size = 9
        min_size, max_size = 3, 40
        self.size_slider = wx.Slider(
            self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, init_size, min_size, max_size, (30, 60), (250, -1), 
            wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)

        self.log = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "DPI:%d SIZE:%d" %(init_dpi, init_size))
        image_latex1 = self.create_lateximage(init_dpi, init_size)
        image_latex2 = self.create_lateximage(init_dpi, init_size, replace_parenthesis=True)
        self.sizer.Add(image_latex1, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(image_latex2, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.dpi_slider, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.size_slider, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.dpi_slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_CHANGED, self.OnSliderChanged)
        self.size_slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_CHANGED, self.OnSliderChanged)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()

    def create_lateximage(self, dpi, size, replace_parenthesis=False):
        updatedProps = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(family = "sans-serif",\
                                                       style = "normal",\
                                                       weight = "medium",\
                                                       size = size)
        if replace_parenthesis:
            tp_exp = EXP.replace("right)", "right]")
            tp_exp = tp_exp.replace("left(", "left[")
            return LatexBitmapFactory().SetBitmap(self.panel, tp_exp, dpi=dpi, prop=updatedProps)
        return LatexBitmapFactory().SetBitmap(self.panel, EXP, dpi=dpi, prop=updatedProps)

    def OnSliderChanged(self, evt):
        dpi  = int(self.dpi_slider.GetValue())
        size = int(self.size_slider.GetValue())
        self.log.SetLabel("DPI:%d SIZE:%d" %(dpi, size))

        self.Freeze()
        new_image_latex1 = self.create_lateximage(dpi, size)
        new_image_latex2 = self.create_lateximage(dpi, size, True)
        prev_image_latex1 = self.sizer.Remove(0)
        prev_image_latex2 = self.sizer.Remove(0)
        del prev_image_latex1
        del prev_image_latex2

        self.sizer.Insert(0, new_image_latex2, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Insert(0, new_image_latex1, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Layout()
        assert len(self.sizer.GetChildren()) == 5,\
        " must have len 5, now %d"%len(self.sizer.GetChildren())
        self.panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.panel.SetScrollRate(100,100)
        self.Thaw()

app = wx.App(redirect=True, filename="latexlog.txt")
frame = aFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - I think that the `dpi` idea was a red herring.  I think I just happened to hit a case that worked.  Sorry about that.  See the updates to my answer, @Baptiste's answer and the github bug for more info.  Nice tool to test with, by the way :)

Comment: If you need a workaround while this is being investigate - you could try swapping to `\right\}`.  In dpi/fontsize combinations where the exclamation appears, that seems even nearer to your desired output than the square bracket workaround. However - when the original work, the braces workaround give - well - braces.  It seems really hard to find a pattern in which ones work and which fail.